# Connecting to Xero Accounting API from my React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, axios, xero-api

I am trying to connect to the Xero Accounting API locally from my react app. I have a this API call setup so it sends a call to the backend authorize and then I have a callback API call that'll return a access_token that I can use to make calls for data.

This is the code that I am using to make the calls to the Xero API

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import useXero from "../../hooks/useXero";

const SigninToXero: React.FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const authorizationCode = queryParams.get("code");

  const handleAuthorizeClick = () => {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:4000/authorize";
  };

  return <button onClick={handleAuthorizeClick}>Authorize Xero</button>;
};

export default SigninToXero;
```

```
const express = require("express");
const xero = express.Router();
const schemas = require("../models/schemas");

const clientId = "xxx";
const clientSecret = "xxx";
const redirectUri = "http://localhost:4000/callback";

xero.get('/authorize', (_, res) => {
  // Redirect users to the Xero authorization endpoint
  const authorizeUrl = `https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
  res.redirect(authorizeUrl);
});

xero.get("/callback", async (req, res) => {
  const authorizationCode = req.query.code;

  // Exchange authorization code for an access token
  const tokenResponse = await axios.post(
    "https://identity.xero.com/connect/token",
    null,
    {
      params: {
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        code: authorizationCode,
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      },
    }
  );

  const accessToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
  res.send("Access token obtained successfully", accessToken);
});

module.exports = xero;
```

Here is the code for the node server

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const router = require("./routes/router");
const xero = require("./routes/xero")
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv/config");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use("/", router);
app.use("/", xero)

const dbOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB_URI, dbOptions)
  .then(() => console.log("DB connected!"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I am expecting a response from the API that says 'Access token obtained successfully, (Access Token)

Answer (score -1):

Xero's API does not currently support single page apps. You will be able to connect to a Xero organisation but calls will not work.

The https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/overview/ documentation mentions SPAs are not currently supported.

Comment: If I had API calls to the backend that would use the api would that work? The backend is Node.js

Comment: There is a node.js SDK you can use to test https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node